# Google Analytics Remarketing Tag (custom dimensions) on Shopify

Tags: google-analytics, shopify

I have looked everywhere for this and cant seem to find an answer.  I am trying to add Google Adwords Dynamic Remarketing to a Shopify site via Google Analytics Tag (I can not use the Adwords Tag, it has to be Google analytics).  The instructions to do this live [here, under retail](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3455600).  It is simple enough but Shopify embeds the Google Analytics library via its own manager.  The issue I think I am having is that when I add the below code to the theme page it is executing after the ga('send', 'pageview) action and google says it needs to happen before it.

```
{% if template == 'product' %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ga('set','dimension1','shopify_US_{{ product.id }}_{{ product.variants.first.id }}');
    ga('set','dimension2','{{ template }}');
  {% if product.selected_variant.price %}
  ga('set','dimension3',{{ product.selected_variant.price | money_without_currency }});
  {% else %}
   ga('set','dimension3',{{ product.price_min | money_without_currency }});
  {% endif %}
</script> 
{% endif %}
```

have any of you done this before? 
Thanks

Comment: This isn't the best response, so I didn't submit it as an answer specifically, but it's an idea if you can't figure it out: Dimension data is sent for both pageviews and events, so you could send one event at the end and the dimensions will be sent with it. Again, you mentioned the ideal being setting these before the pageview send, and that is correct, but an event may be an option if you have no other recourse. Just make sure the event is sent with non-interaction added!

Comment: Thanks @GreatBlakes!  I did think about doing this but I was trying to figure out how to avoid hacking a solution together but maybe that is what I have to do.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Shopify, so maybe someone else can chime in that has more experience on that end before you have to use my idea.

Comment: did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Right before `</script>`,
try inserting `ga('send', 'pageview');`